# how do I use multiple functions in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a beginner in SQL and using PostgresSQL 14. I have two table customer and payment and the columns are.

**customer table**

```
customer_id int
first_name chr
email chr
```

**payment table**

```
customer_id int
payment_date date  
amount numeric
```

My desired output is to get `customer id, email id and total amount paid by customer and payment_date`.

This is my output using inner join.

[image]

Now I want to sum amount using GROUP BY, but how do I use INNER JOIN and GROUP BY together?

How do I run two different things together? Is there way to save output and work on it like a script?

Comment: You can join and group in the same query, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use in SELECT `SUM(column_name)`
For your inner join, in GROUP BY you need to put everything you choose to show in select except for operations like `SUM`you don't have to write it in group by.

Comment: Select date(payment_date), customer.customer_id, email, sum(amount) 
from customer
INNER JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id    where should I put group by?

Comment: You should becouse data may not match.
Try Group By customer.customer_id, email

Comment: Select date(payment_date), customer.customer_id, email, sum(amount)
from customer
group by customer.customer_id, email, date(payment_date)
INNER JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id

Comment: inner join should be after SELECT do not group by date(payment_date) only customer_id and email should do the work